# Taking a screenshot in-app then putting it in a UIImageView does so at normal resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, retina-display

After zooming the iOS simulator up to 100%, i've noticed that my icons which are made by the app through taking a 'screenshot' of a view using this code are in normal resolution, whereas everything else appears to be in retina resolution:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[object.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Any ideas how to make it be in retina resolution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` is not Retina display-aware.

On iOS 4, you'll need to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` instead, passing `0` as the last argument to have iOS automatically scale it based on the device's screen resolution:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
[object.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```